# How to export from DB Sku - Order Number - Quantity Sold?

Tags: database, orders, export, quantity

Does anybody know how to export from PhpMyAdmin the Quantity sold by products and by Order Number ?

I've already found Sku and Qty Sold in the table Sales_flat_order but I really don't know how to join with order number.

Any idea ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you send what you have tried so far?

Comment: I've simpy exported the table from DB, then open it with MS Excel, then remove all columns except "SKU" and "Qty Ordered".

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT `item`.`sku`, `item`.`qty_ordered`, `main`.`increment_id` 
FROM `sales_flat_order_item` as `item` 
LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_order` as `main` 
ON `main`.`entity_id` = `item`.`order_id`
```